# Pulling in a title from multiple content types

Tags: 7, views

Currently I have 3 content types: Program, Chapter, Item. The program content type has a node reference field to contain multiple chapters and the chapters content type has a node reference to contain multiple items.

I now have a view that lists some items, but I also want to pull in the program title that is referencing that item.

For example:

Program = Fruit
Chapter = Pear
Item = Cutting a Pear

I want to list the title of "Cutting a pear" and also the program "fruit" title.

In my view for my items I tried creating a relationship to tie in the "program", but the only relationship that I can use is the "Chapter" because I guess its directly related to the item. The program is not tied to it in any way.

Any ideas how I can pull in the program title information when its not directly related to the item?

Answer (score 1):

I would put this as a comment, but I'm new so I can't comment on things yet, but what you could do is add the relationship of the chapter, then add a field using that relationship that shows the node reference that the chapter has to the program. As long as you're using that relationship, it should show the proper program.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I am having trouble adding a field as you say that shows the node reference. I added a relationship "Content: Chapters (field_chapters)" and then add the field "Content: Chapters (field_chapters)". I then add the relationship, but I dont get any output.

Comment: Add the relationship to chapters, then add the field that the chapters content uses to reference the program, using the relationship you created.